# How to validate bean when saving entity on a batch job

Tags: validation, javabeans, java-ee-6, bean-validation

I'm wondering if it's possible to have something like bean validation in UI (for example in jsf or primefaces) to be implemented or executed when saving an entity on backend. For example I have a job that import customers from 1 system to another. Of course I'll do the parsing and saving of the records, but the problem is the data might not match. Some values might be longer than the field can hold.

Aside from checking the fields manually one by one, is there an efficient way to address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JPA for persistence, then event based validation of entities (on life cycle events like pre-persist, pre-update and pre-delete) is per default enabled in a EE 6 environment. All you need to do is to start placing constraints on your entities (or add the right xml configuration files to configure constraints via XML).

Comment: But how will you handle that and throw the appropriate error. For example column a is only 50 chars in length but you enter 100? In UI JSF can handle these validations, but how in job :-?

Comment: You have to handle exceptions anyways, even in a batch job, right? You might have to, for example, re-run a certain job, because something failed. I am not an expert in the exact API here, but I would assume there is a way to catch occurring exceptions and handle them at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by injecting Validate and manually validating the beans:

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-validate-javaee6-bean-in-job.html